# set PATH with multiple lines

Tags: batch-file

In a Batch file I need to add some paths to the PATH env variable. Since its a larger numer of long paths I tried to spread them on multiple line and tried to make the bat-file as clean as I can by indenting the lines.

But it seems that the spaces at the beginning of the newline (and so in the %PATH%) are interpreted as part of the actual path. 
So

```
SET PATH=^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3;^
    %PATH%
```

does not work (programs are not found). Is there some trick I can use?
Because it is a medium complex batch file some indentation would be nice.

Comment: I think you have to place a leading `;` there as the Path variable usually is ending without one. have you tried checking the value of the variable using `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: Remove the indent spaces and it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have PATH ignore the leading spaces. I see two possible options if you want indented lines:

**Option 1 - Use undefined variable to indent, so spaces never get in the value**

```
@echo off
SET PATH=^
%    =%\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin;^
%    =%\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin;^
%    =%\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin;^
%    =%\\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3;^
%    =%%PATH%
```

**Option 2 - Remove the spaces afterwards**

```
@echo off
SET PATH=^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin;^
    \\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3;^
    %PATH%
set "PATH=%PATH:;    =%"
```

Comment: sorry, the %PATH% was lost during copy&paste

Answer (score 4):

```
for %%x in (
    "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin;"
    "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin;"
    "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin;"
    "\\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3;"
) do call set "path=%%path%%%%~x"
```

this will **append** the extra items to the `path`. You'd need to initialise `path` to *nothing* first if all you want is to build the directory sequence specified.

Comment: I was in the process of adding this option to my answer when your answer popped up :-) So I canceled my edit

Comment: since i would like to add in front of path, this would reverse the order of the new paths, so that they have to be specified counter intuitively in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

First let me start by informing you that adding to the PATH variable in this way is ONLY for the running session. Once the cmd session is closed that variable returns to its previous value.

Here are a suggestion, append each addition one by one:

```bat
SET "ToAdd=\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin;"
SET "ToAdd=%ToAdd%;\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin;"
SET "ToAdd=%ToAdd%;\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin;"
SET "ToAdd=%ToAdd%;\\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3"
SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ToAdd%"
```

BTW, if you were hoping to add to the environment variable beyond the running session then it is important that you ignore anyone suggesting you use SETX instead of SET. *(the variable will be truncated at 1024 bytes therefore corrupting it)*. Your best solutions would involve editing the registry and possibly using a built in tool such as powershell.

**Edit**

This shows the method mentioned in my comment and uses the same structure as Magoo's answer:

**C:\MyDir\Paths.txt**

```
\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin
\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin
\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin
\\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3
```

**batch file**

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQDelims=" %%A In ("C:\MyDir\paths.txt") Do Set "Path=!Path!;%%~A"
Echo(%Path%
EndLocal
Timeout -1
```

This means that you only really need to include the for loop each time instead of adding each of the paths to it.

Comment: This solution is imho awkward. Iam fully aware that this modification is bould to the session. Since iam also using setlocal it is even more restricted to the runtime of the batch script

Comment: It's no more awkward than the other solutions, and here's why, you have to create it every time you're intending to use those tools. Using cut and paste in the script editor really doesn't make the file any more awkward. What I'd suggest you do is create a file containing the lines you wish to add to the variable and then parse that file each time instead of recreating the code, that would be less awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Not even remotely bulletproof, but the Magoo's answer reminded me this. Just because someone, somewhere, could find a better usage for this construct

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims="  %%a in ('echo "%path:;=" "%"

        "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\site\bin"
        "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\perl\bin"
        "\\somewhere\Tools\strawberryperl\c\bin"
        "\\somewhere\Tools\KDiff3"

    ""') do (set "path=%%~a") & call set "path=%%path:" "=;%%"

    path
```